# AVAudioSession setPreferredSampleRate not working on iPhone 11 and above

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have a legacy video streaming library that seems to be broken on iPhone 11 (and above) devices. After digging into the problem it seems that the code that is initiating the AVAudioSession is failing due to the call to `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance.setPreferredSampleRate(44100)` not changing the actual sample rate and keeping it at 48000Hz.

Has anyone else faced this? I know that the method says `preferred` and it is not guaranteed that it will change the audio sample rate, but it was working on all previous devices.